# How to inject IL with constant in run-time?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0

I know how to create a dynamic method by injecting IL for say a * 2;

However I want to be it like a * b where b is consntant.

Consider this.

```
int b = SomeClassInstance.Multiplier;

Func<int,int> MultA = CreateDynMethod(b);

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    int a = GetValueSomewhere();
    int result = MultA(a);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

See.. b is the same for all 1000 iteration. However I dont know what it is going to be. 0 1 2 or whatever.

My question is how can I embed the b value in IL as a constant.

This is very important distinction - I **dont want** to calculate var a * var b. **I want (if for example b == 2 in run-time) to create IL which does a * 2.**

I have reason to do so. If you please answer the question as it written. Thank you.

**EDIT. Here is what I could write with your help. Please tell what do you think**

```
    static Func<int, int> IL_EmbedConst(int b)
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("EmbedConst", typeof(int), new[] { typeof(int) } );

        var il = method.GetILGenerator();

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, b);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Func<int, int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int>));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`ldc.i4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4.aspx) opcode.

That will load an int onto the stack, which can then be followed by a `mul`.

You could use it like this:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, b);
```

By the way, you don't really need to build methods from IL here. This method would work as well:

```
Func<int, int> CreateDynMethod(int b)
{
    return a => a * b;
}
```

Comment: From memory (haven't checked today), I *don't* think it optimizes to the `ldc.i4.[b]` opcodes, but the JIT  probably *does* do a quick check on that, so probably not important

Comment: @MarcGravell: I just did a (not so) quick test, and you are right. Now I need to figure out why I thought that.

Comment: Yes it works. thanks a lot! Let me benchmark it against the func

Comment: @Bobb: Don't expect it to be much faster. The C# compiler + JIT compiler are *very* smart.

Comment: Thanks again Kendall, evidently your CreateDynMethod 2x faster than IL injected dynamic method... but why?

Comment: Like I said, it is hard to hand-write faster code than C# compiles to. Also, building a method from IL at runtime is slower than using a pre-built method that the lambda generates.

Comment: cost of building is not important. this method built once will be used 100 mil times. then other will be built and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to emit something like

```
 ldarg.1
 ldc.i4 2
 mul
 ret
```

You can emit the second line using

```
 il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
```

or, just to be clear:

```
 int b = 2;
 il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, b);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3c68sh6
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4